# Transform Travel Table - SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

Table:

| Student | Travel Date | Travel Location | Visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stud1 | 25-03-2023 | loc1 | 2 |
| stud1 | 27-03-2023 | loc2 | 1 |
| stud1 | 24-03-2022 | loc3 | 1 |
| stud2 | 15-02-2022 | loc2 | 3 |
| stud3 | 07-07-2022 | loc3 | 1 |

Above is a travel table with travel date, location and total visits to that location. The expected output is to find the travel journey mapping like below:

Output:

| Student | Travel*_location1* | Travel_location2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stud1 | loc3 | loc1 |
| stud1 | loc1 | loc2 |
| stud2 | loc2 | null |
| stud3 | loc3 | null |

stud1 has loc3 as first location based on travel date, and then comes loc1, second row continues with same logic, and also the 'travel location 2' from 1st row should be repeated as 'travel location 1' in 2nd row

Thanks for the help

Comment: How about using `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: or maybe `LAG`?

Comment: Which version of Oracle you using ?

Comment: could you pls share the script with ROW_NUMBER() @Tushar, thanks

Comment: @Eric Well here is the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3931b5/3 using your data. It is different output than your expectation though

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Travel
GO
CREATE TABLE #Travel(
  Student VARCHAR(10),
  TravelDate DATETIME,
  TravelLocation VARCHAR(50),
  Visits INT);

INSERT INTO #Travel
VALUES
  ('Stud1','2023-03-25 00:00','loc1',2),
  ('Stud1','2023-03-27 00:00','loc2',1),
  ('Stud1','2023-03-24 00:00','loc3',1),
  ('Stud2','2022-02-15 00:00','loc2',3),
  ('Stud3','2022-07-07 00:00','loc3',1);

WITH CTE1 AS (
  select Student, TravelLocation 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student ORDER BY TravelDate ) AS RowNum
  from #Travel
)
SELECT 
  Travel.Student,
  Travel.TravelLocation AS TravelLocation1,
  NextTravel.TravelLocation AS TravelLocation2
FROM CTE1 Travel
LEFT JOIN CTE1 NextTravel ON Travel.Student = NextTravel.Student 
                        AND NextTravel.RowNum = Travel.RowNum+1
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by student and use the LEAD() function:

```
select student, travel_location as travel_location1,
lead(travel_location, 1) over (partition by student order by travel_date) as travel_location2
from your_travel_table
```

LEAD(field_name, number_of_records)
OVER (PARTITION BY group_columns ORDER BY order_columns)
will return the value in (field_name) that is (number_of_records) rows after the "current" row in order_columns order, except that it will ignore all rows where the value(s) in the group_columns column(s) are different.

LAG() does the same thing, except that it counts (number_of_records) rows before the "current" row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: OLAP functions `LEAD()` (for the following travel location) and `ROW_NUMBER()` for the filter returning the only present row or only the rows with a non-null `travel_location_2`:

```
WITH
indata(Student,Travel_Date,Travel_Location,Visits) AS (
          SELECT 'stud1',DATE '03-25-2023','loc1',2
UNION ALL SELECT 'stud1',DATE '03-27-2023','loc2',1
UNION ALL SELECT 'stud1',DATE '03-24-2022','loc3',1
UNION ALL SELECT 'stud2',DATE '02-15-2022','loc2',3
UNION ALL SELECT 'stud3',DATE '07-07-2022','loc3',1
)
,
w_next AS (
  SELECT
    student
  , travel_date
  , travel_location AS travel_location_1
  , LEAD(travel_location) OVER(PARTITION BY student ORDER BY travel_date) AS travel_location_2
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY student ORDER BY travel_date) AS rn -- needed as filter ...
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  student
, travel_location_1
, travel_location_2
FROM w_next
WHERE travel_location_2 IS NOT NULL
   OR rn                = 1
ORDER BY student,travel_date;
-- out  student | travel_location_1 | travel_location_2 
-- out ---------+-------------------+-------------------
-- out  stud1   | loc3              | loc1
-- out  stud1   | loc1              | loc2
-- out  stud2   | loc2              | (null)
-- out  stud3   | loc3              | (null)
```